# How to stop an upcoming alarm trigger

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

```
public class MyAlarm implements IAlarm {
    AlarmManager manager;
    private Context context;

    public MyAlarm(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    }

    public void set(int notificationId, int day, int hour, int minute, String title, String description) {
        //Set up the Notification Broadcast Intent
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("description", description);

        //Set up the PendingIntent for the AlarmManager
        final PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (context, notificationId, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        long triggerTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        Log.v("Alarm", triggerTime+"");

        // to have an interval with in a week multiply INTERVAL_DAY by 7
        long repeatInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7;

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                triggerTime, repeatInterval, notifyPendingIntent);
        Log.v("Alarm"," Alarm is setted");

    }

    public void cancel(int notificationId, String title, String description) {
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("description", description);

        final PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (context, notificationId, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //Cancel the alarm and notification if the alarm is turned off
        Log.v("Alarm", notifyPendingIntent.toString());
        manager.cancel(notifyPendingIntent);
        notifyPendingIntent.cancel();
    }

    public boolean isAlarmSet(int notificationId, String title, String description) {
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("description", description);

        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, notifyIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
        return alarmUp;
    }

}
```

Here is my alarm class to set, cancel and check if alarm is set from an activity.
The problem that i faced is, set method only accepts DAY, HOUR and Minute and it repeats every week (after 7 day), so whenever i set an alarm that is different from today the alarm will trigger immediately but i don't want that to happen. I want the alarm trigger at a specific day, hour and minute.

Sample scenario, if i set an alarm for tomorrow(MONDAY, 10:10), the alarm will trigger immediately.

Comment: Not very clear, you set alarm triggered in Monday, if today is Sunday, why the alarm be triggered?

Comment: That is the problem @navylover.  Monday -----> Sunday -> Monday, i think it uses the previous Monday, how to make it to use the next Monday.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

//set Calendar to next week
int i = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, ++i); 

calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
...
```